# Grande vs Gran usage

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, plurales

> Los grandes imperios han dominado la humanidad.

Why not can't gran replace grandes in the sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque 'gran' es singular, y 'grandes' es plural, entonces si estas refiriendote a varios imperios debes usar el plural que es 'grandes', si te refirieras a un solo (only one) imperio si podrias y deberias usar gran en lugar de grandes de la siguiente manera:

> el gran imperio ha dominado la humanidad

y en plural, tal cual tu lo escribiste

> Los grandes imperios han dominado la humanidad.

Answer (score 1):

*Grande* es un adjetivo calificativo equivalente a "Big" y "Great".

> Esa camisa es muy grande para ti. (big)
>
> Ese músico es muy grande (es magnífico). (great, since you are praising. You are referring to the "size" of his talent. But you could use it for his physical size too...)

*Gran* es el [apócope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope) de grande y se usa en contextos relativos. Tiene la idea de "magnífico", "estupendo". *Gran* se coloca antes del sustantivo, mientras que *grande* como adjetivo que es, normalmente ira detrás.

> Es un gran músico. (magnífico)
>
> El gran (grandioso) imperio de Carlomagno...

Comment: I think it is easy to understand that explanation, but let me know if you need further explanations in English.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Is grandes used because the noun following is plural?

Comment: I edited the question, let me know if it is more clear now.